Changing pkgselect configuration in calamares installer
I am the one who reorganized Lubuntu with Cubic for use at my university. My problem is that in version 24.04 I don't know where is the configuration file for the pkgselect and pkgselect snap modules in the calamares installer, where the text that appears in the graphical interface, etc. is set. In the repository of calamares settings on the Github page, these files are in the common/modules/pkgselect folder, but I couldn't find them when I checked the ISO. I looked in /etc/calamares and /usr/share/calamares but they are not there either. My last suspicious location was /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu (I may have misspelled it) /calamares/modules/pkgselect/ (I don't remember the exact name of the file but I know it's extension is .so, there are already two files in this location)
If you are someone who set up this calamares script, can you explain how the extra modules work?

You've asked this on a Ubuntu user support site; which is not where I'd have asked this question. If I wanted an answer like you do, I'd likely have asked on Lubuntu's discourse/forum (ie. https://discourse.lubuntu.me/) in the off-topic area as you're not wanting Lubuntu support; but wanting to modify Lubuntu for your own needs.  The Lubuntu discourse will get the eyes you see unlike this site. Note: setup for noble differs slightly as three flavors are now using the code when compared to prior releases, and it'll change again too for oracular to streamline common code...

The question was asked (again as suggested) at https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/how-can-i-access-the-gui-settings-of-the-pkgselect-module-in-calamares/4862/

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/calamares/modules/pkgselect contains the actual compiled module itself.
The configuration files are where you’d expect in /etc/calamares/modules. There are two (pkgselect_context.conf and pkgselect_snap_context.conf). The “snap” one uses /usr/bin/snap-seed-glue, for what it's worth.
…but if you want to change the way the module looks, you’ll have to edit the actual code and recompile. In particular, it's the pkgselect.ui file. Here are not only the strings but also the whole layout.
